# Is it possible to get worker number on heroku with multiple web concurrency?

Tags: heroku, concurrency

Is it possible get web worker number inside application when web_concurrency > 1.
In logs we have web.1 and web.2, for ex.
But how to get it in the app ?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the index of the current dyno, then use [the DYNO environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables).

If you need to also know the quantity of dynos configured for your app, then use the Platform API to [retrieve the formation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation). 
The URL you would need to query is:
https://api.heroku.com/apps/your_app_name/formation/web
The field you would need is "quantity".

Note that you would need to pass an [authentication token in the authorization header](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#authentication).